# Popup isn't clicked by selenium driver

Tags: python, selenium, automation, uipath

I'm having a problem where the following pop-up only appears when I run python selenium in incognito mode, and I can't click it. When I use Chrome, though, that does not happen. I assumed it was because of the cookies. I attempted to add all the cookies to the selenium driver, but was unsuccessful. Any advice or assistance is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This pop-up is an *Alert*.
Since here you want to click on `Cancel` button you want to dismiss this alert.
With Selenium in Python it can be done as following:

```py
driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()
```

Comment: Tried that one, but didn't work

Comment: maybe you need to wait for the alert appearance?

Comment: What exactly did not work? What is the error?

Comment: When i use, driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss() nothing changes and never the pop-up never disappear without manual intervention.

Comment: I see... We need to do some debugging here while your question is missing such details.